# Does the approximation property pass to subspaces?

Tags: banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ has the approximation property (AP) if for any compact subset $K$ of $X$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a bounded finite rank operator $R$ such that $\| x - R(x) \| < \epsilon$ for every $x \in K$.

Question: If $M \subset X$ is a subspace which does not have AP, then $X$ does not have AP too.

I have the feeling that it is true. But I don't know how to show it. Any idea?

Comment: @soup: so you think that the statement holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben has answered your question, but here is an even easier route to a counter-example (modulo the hard part of the existence of a space without the AP).

Take your favourite separable space without the AP. [You may embed it into](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) $C[0,1]$, which actually has a basis ([the Schauder system](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Faber-Schauder_system), a prototypical example of a Schauder basis), so in particular it has the AP.

Answer (score 2):

Every $\ell_p$, $p\neq 2$, and $c_0$ have closed subspaces without the ap. So the answer to your question is **no**.